# strange behavior of polymer data biding

Tags: data-binding, polymer

Assume that I have three tabs together,content in each tab are fetched via `core-ajax`

```
       <core-ajax auto url="http://example.com/tab.json" handleAs="json" 
response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>


<paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="{{response[0].name}}" flex  >
              <template repeat="{{mytab as t}}">
                <paper-tab name="{{t.name}}">{{t.name}}</paper-tab>
              </template>
</paper-tabs>




 Polymer({
      responseChanged:function(response){
         this.mytab= this.response;
         console.log(this.mytab[0].name);
      }
    });
```

codes above display normal,but what is confusing me is that,when i click the other two tabs other than the first one,the first one tab name(i.e. content) changes accordingly to the name of which tab was clicked.i can't get that ,can  anyone explain to me ?

Thanks

Peng

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to solve this problem,but i don't know if this is the right way or the best:

```
  <core-ajax auto url="http://example.com/tab.json" handleAs="json" 
response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>

                                  (changed)
<paper-tabs id="tabs" selected="{{defaulttab}}" flex  >
              <template repeat="{{mytab as t}}">
                <paper-tab name="{{t.name}}">{{t.name}}</paper-tab>
              </template>
</paper-tabs>




 Polymer({
      responseChanged:function(response){
         this.mytab= this.response;
         this.defaulttab = this.response[0].name;(added)
         console.log(this.mytab[0].name);
      }
    });
```

This works as expected.